# How to add generated image in embed | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i was generated an image with "easy_pil" libray and i need to paste this image in to my embed, how can i do this using `embed.set_image`?

Generated image code:

```
background = Editor('./assets/card_1.jpg').resize((900, 300))

background.rectangle((30,220), width=600, height=30, fill='#C0B6CC', radius=20)
background.bar((30,220), max_width=600, height=30, percentage=90, fill='#7600FF', radius=20)

file = File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename='card.png')
```

Comment: Have you try reading [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#local-image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```python
file = File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="card.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://card.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

*Source: https://discordpy.rtfd.org/en/stable/faq.html#local-image*